# UISegmentedControl with Badge or Highlighting

Tags: iphone, ios, uisegmentedcontrol, badge

Occasionally I want to highlight one of segments of a `UISegmentedControl`, i.e. the third title is "News" and I want to draw user's attention to it. Ideally with a red badge with a number as on the `UITabBar` - any idea how to achieve this? Feel free to share other ideas as well. I thought about adding the badge as an image just on top of it, but maybe there is some better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't have thought there is a better way to be honest.

The easiest way will be (probably) to subclass uisegmentedcontrol and add a badge label to it. Or something similar. (subclass uiview add a uisegmentedcontrol to it and add a badge label to it).

Comment: It would be nice if the batches were available separately. Maybe I'll prerender some images or use an "!" instead.