# Facebook-Messages-like Bar Button Items?

Tags: iphone, uikit

I just want to create those buttons at the bottom of the image attached saying "Messages", "Updates", "Sent".

Are these buttons ready-made UIKit buttons? if so what controls are they?

Thank you!

F.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [UISegmentedControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html), but I don't think there is support for the badge (the red circle with the number inside). Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669673/uisegmentedcontrol-with-badge-or-highlighting) for a similar reply.

You can also have a look to the [three20 library](http://three20.info/), as Facebook is based on that and there might be a class with exactly what you need.

Comment: Great I just needed the UISegmentedControl however I keep your links for future reference! Thank you! F.

Answer (score 1):

That is [UISegmentedControl](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-segmented-controluisegmentedcontrol-tutorial/) .. check out the link for tutorial...

hAPPY iCODNG...

Comment: I knew it was simple.. Thank you! F.

Answer (score 0):

And here's the code for it, as found in the documentation under "Navigation Controllers" in the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html):

**Listing 3-3** Configuring a toolbar with a centered segmented control

```
- (void)configureToolbarItems
{
   UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpaceButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                        initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                        target:nil action:nil];

   // Create and configure the segmented control
   UISegmentedControl *sortToggle = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]
                        initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Ascending",
                                        @"Descending", nil]];
   sortToggle.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
   sortToggle.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
   [sortToggle addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleSorting:)
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

   // Create the bar button item for the segmented control
   UIBarButtonItem *sortToggleButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                    initWithCustomView:sortToggle];
   [sortToggle release];

   // Set our toolbar items
   self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         flexibleSpaceButtonItem,
                         sortToggleButtonItem,
                         flexibleSpaceButtonItem,
                         nil];

   [sortToggleButtonItem release];
   [flexibleSpaceButtonItem release];
}
```

F.